# How to detect NAT(Network Address Translation) or PAT(Port Address Translation) is enabled

Tags: .net, windows, networking, network-programming, winapi

I need help to detect NAT or PAT is enabled on network or not. Is there any way in Windows SDK or .NET to detect this?

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 1):

google STUN. It's defined by RFC. It's used to determine the nat type and mapped address.